# How to edit this table filter script to get results by a predifined search string?

Tags: javascript, html, date, filter

I am using this script:

```
var LightTableFilter = (function(Arr) {

    var _input;

    function _onInputEvent(e) {
        _input = e.target;
        var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
        Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
            Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
                Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
            });
        });
    }

    function _filter(row) {
        var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
        row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    }

    return {
        init: function() {
            var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
            Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
                input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
            });
        }
    };
})(Array.prototype);

document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        LightTableFilter.init();
    }
});

})(document);
```

and this input:

```
<input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="order-table">
```

When I type something in the filter input, it filters a table so I see only entries I have in there matching the text. Like this: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/tIuBL.
Now I have a table with a date column. I'd like to display only the dates of the current month. So no user input should be needed anymore. 
I tried to replace the input with the current month without success. :-/ Has someone a suggestion?

Comment: I can't see a date column in your codepen. Please provide a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example": http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the format of the date string in the column? Rather than toggling between `'none' : 'table-row'` consider `'none' : ''` so it can be used on any type of element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this is done on the client, it means you're sending more data than is necessary and you're trusting that the client time setting is accurate. So it would be better to do it on the server so you don't get more data than you need, don't send redundant data to the client and aren't dependent on the client time setting or scripting.

Anyway, presuming your date format is dd/mm/yyyy then can get the current month in the required format using:

```
var m = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
var monthString = '/' + ('0' + m).slice(-2) + '/';
```

now when hiding the rows use:

```
row.style.display = text.indexOf(monthString) === -1 ? 'none' : '';
```

Of course you can modify *monthString* to be whatever suits.

I prefer to undo hiding things with *display* by setting them to '' (empty string), that way they adopt their default or inherited style, whatever that might be and I don't have to know what it is.

I'd also suggest you target just the cell with the date in it just in case the row's *textContent* concatenates some other strings into a false positive, so:

```
var text = row.cells[i].textContent.toLowerCase()
```

where *i* is the index of the cell with the date in it.